# What is the best practice to store multi valued/repeated data in google datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple scenario where I have 4 entities.

1. **Destination** : name, location, tags (multi valued), created, last modified, created by, last modified by
2. **Trip** : contains multiple ***Destinations***, name, tags (multi valued), created, last modified, created by, last modified by
3. **Question** : question, multiple ***Answers***, created, last modified, created by, last modified by
4. **Answer** : ***Destinations*** (multiple), ***Trips*** (multiple), created, last modified, created by, last modified by

I am using Google Datastore. What should be a best approach to store this kind of data?

Comment: Do you want to know how best to model the relationships between the objects?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer to my question. Right now I am using `ndb.KeyProperty` in `Google Datastore` to solve my problem.

```
class Trip(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    details = ndb.TextProperty()
    turl = ndb.StringProperty()
    links = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
    tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
    destinations = ndb.KeyProperty(Destination1, repeated = True)

class Destination1(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    location = ndb.StringProperty()
    durl = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.StringProperty()
    deatils = ndb.StringProperty()
    tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
    links = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
```

This concept of nested `repeated=True` was not supported in the `StructredProperty` which I was using earlier.